# getting a specific key value from a dictionary nested within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a specific key value from a dictionary nested within a list
Hello,
**Code **

```
students = [
    {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Otter"},
    {"name": "Harry", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Stag"},
    {"name": "Ron", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Jack Russell terrier"},
    {"name": "Draco", "house": "Slytherin", "patronus": None}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**I tried this **

```
next (item for item in students if item ["patronus"] == "Stag")
```

But this get me the following

```
{"name": "Harry", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Stag"},
```

**What i expect**

Stag

Comment: `next(item["patronus"] for....` ?

Comment: What's the point of this? It will always return the value that you're looking for. Why wouldn't you want the rest of the related data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the problem doesn't make sense.But here is a solution for you.
You are getting complete row/dict because you are asking for item(thats the complte dict) , if you just want the stag, you have to ask for that particular key.

```py
x=[i["patronus"] for i in students if i.get("patronus")=='Stag']
print(x[0] if x else None)
```

Comment: I am a novice learner, I agree problem doesn't make sense. I was just wondering how to get this. Thank you

Comment: @MK980 , no problem. keep learning